# NSJSONSerialization not working as intended for Stack overflow API

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5

I am trying to use NSJSONSerialization to serialize the data returned from stack overflow API, but it is not working as intended :(

I am using code as below :

```
NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?tagged=objective-c&pagesize=30"];

NSError *error = nil;

// First option - failed
NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:apiURL]; // returning nil
id jsonFound1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:inputStream options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

// Second option - failed
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:apiURL]; // returning correct value, verified after converting it to NSString

id jsonFound2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];  // returning nil
```

I am trying the above code in Xcode 4.2 for iOS5 and I am getting (null) for **inputStream** and for **jsonFound2**.

Earlier I was doing it through SBJSON and it was working correctly.

Can anyone suggest me if I am doing anything wrong or missing anything?

Comment: If `inputStream` is `nil` then everything else will fail. It’s not a problem with `NSJSONSerialization`; it’s a problem with your stream. Are you sure `+[NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:]` works with remote URLs?

Comment: ok.. I will check it.. also I tried second option by obtaining data from apiURL and then using JSONObjectWithData:options:error and in this case also I am getting nil :(. Any clue ?

Comment: What does the `error` output parameter contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option does not work because it supports only file url (thanks to David for pointing).

Second option works fine for remote urls.

Comment: The above code can't work fine, "NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:apiURL];" only support file URLs.

Answer (score 3):

I think there may be a missing step after assigning an `inputStream`.

```
[inputStream open];
```

I have not tried this with remote URLs, but have seen examples that use this approach.